# Locating address using geocoder not providing any result

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am implementing Google maps V3, I have a feature to search a location by proving address like '5415 E High St. Suite 460, Phoenix, AZ, 85054' and searching through geocoder and it is not providing me any result. Below is my code snippet. I have searched this same address in bing and it is providing me correct location.

```
var geocoder;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('txtLocation').value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                zoom: 15,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                dragable: true
            });
```

Please let me know where am i going wrong and what should i do to get correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're closing your braces and function calls.  When I made your example into valid JavaScript I had no problem getting it to work:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = document.getElementById('txtLocation').value;

geocoder.geocode({ 
  'address': address 
}, function (results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      zoom: 15,
      position: results[0].geometry.location,
      dragable: true
    });
  }
});
```

You can see it in action on [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iducuk/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

That location works for me, here is a link to a page that displays it:

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?zoom=17&type=m&addr1=5415%20E%20High%20St.%20Suite%20460,%20Phoenix,%20AZ,%2085054&geocode=1)